# Server accept many clients

Tags: c, sockets

How can I modify my server to accept many clients?

```
void Serveur()
{//Declaring process variables.
    int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
    int server_len ; 
    int rc ; 
    unsigned client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;

    //Remove any old socket and create an unnamed socket for the server.
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(1111) ; 
    server_len = sizeof(server_address);

    rc = bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, server_len);
    printf("RC from bind = %d\n", rc ) ; 

    //Create a connection queue and wait for clients
    rc = listen(server_sockfd, 5);
    printf("RC from listen = %d\n", rc ) ; 

    client_len = sizeof(client_address);
    client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &client_len);
    printf("after accept()... client_sockfd = %d\n", client_sockfd) ; 
    char ch[BUFFER_TAILLE];
}
```

Comment: The rest of the code                                            while(1)
 {
  
  printf("server waiting\n");

  
  rc = read(client_sockfd, ch, 3);
                printf("Char from client = %c\n", ch[0]);
  //printf("RC from read = %d\n", rc ) ;   
  if (ch[0]=='X') break ; 
                sleep(10);
  ch[0]++;
  write(client_sockfd, ch, 1);
 }

 printf("server exiting\n");

 
 close(client_sockfd);

Comment: @Tom: i'd like to change the code of the server to accept many clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution.

- The first one is to handle each client in a different processus/thread. Follow this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm) for more information (Handle multiple connections part).
- The second one is to use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), and [handle each client in your server loop](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to accept multiple clients you need a couple of things:

1. First of all all your sockets must be non-blocking, i.e. when you call e.g. `read`/`recv` on a client socket it doesn't block but returns immediately if there's nothing to read.
2. You need to learn to use the `select` or `poll` (or similar) functions to know which sockets are ready.
3. You need to keep track of all clients that are connected. It's most simply done by keeping a linked list of structures containing information about each client including the actual socket.
4. An event loop. You need to keep calling e.g. `select` in a loop, and check if the server socket or any client sockets are "ready" (i.e. have input that you can receive).

There are many examples and tutorials on the Internet showing how to do this.

There are also other ways to handle this besides the one I outlined above. The most common is to keep the sockets blocking, and when a new connection arrive you create a new thread or process to handle the client connection. This method is most common in servers like web-servers where client connections are short or when you don't expect to have many active connections.

You can of course combine the methods, like having a process/thread handle multiple connections.